# MS Access 2013: Nested IIF Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I can't figure out why I am receiving a syntax error in access sql for the following nested IIF - it works if I remove the top line and closing parenthesis... Thanks

```
IIF(
  [Home Phone] IS NULL
  AND [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL
, [Home Phone]
, IIF(
    [H1 Cell Phone] IS NOT NULL
  , [H1 Cell Phone] & ' (m)'
  , [Home Phone] & ' (h)'
  ) AS Phone
)
```

Comment: I've reformatted the SQL--which should immediately reveal the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the "AS Phone" part outside of the closing parenthesis. It looks like your IIf can be split up as:

```
IIF(
  [Home Phone] IS NULL AND [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL, -- Conditional
  [Home Phone], -- Conditional true If they're both null, why are you displaying null here?
  -- Conditional false
  IIF(
    [H1 Cell Phone] IS NOT NULL, -- Conditional
    [H1 Cell Phone]&' (m)', - True
    [Home Phone]&' (h)' - False
  ) AS Phone --I think the AS Phone part needs to be moved outside the IIF or removed entirely.
)
```

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx for examples on how to use IIF as well.

Comment: This achieved the desired result, thank you! Final code is:

`IIF([Home Phone] IS NULL AND [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL,NULL,
IIF([H1 Cell Phone] IS NOT NULL, [H1 Cell Phone]&' (m)', [Home Phone]&' (h)') 

) As Phone
`

Answer (score 0):

```
IIF([Home Phone] IS NULL AND [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL,[Home Phone],
IIF([H1 Cell Phone] IS NOT NULL, [H1 Cell Phone]&' (m)', [Home Phone]&' (h)')) AS Phone
```

Parenthesis is misplaced.  You must trouble shoot this in pieces.  Find parts taht work, and build up.

Answer (score 0):

Remember IIF - is constructed with the format: `IIF(SOME_TEST,TRUE_CONDITION,ELSE_FALSE_CONDITION)`

At first glance, you are missing a closing paranthesis..

```
IIF([Home Phone] IS NULL AND [H1 Cell Phone] IS NULL,[Home Phone],

IIF([H1 Cell Phone] IS NOT NULL, [H1 Cell Phone]&' (m)', [Home Phone]&' (h)') AS Phone

))
```